# Load balance LDAPS with Network load balancer Layer 3/Layer 4 (IP protocol)

Tags: load-balancing, ldap

I'm trying to setup a Network Load Balancer which direct traffic to healthy servers based on Layer 3/Layer 4 (IP protocol) data.

**Question: Does this work for LDAP over SSL (LDAPS)?** (I'm aware layer 7 perform TLS/SSL decryption as needed)

I have a Network Load Balancer and my two backend server are running LDAP service.
It is possible to run `ldapsearch` with following result:

| Target | Query | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Backend server1 | `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<Backend1>` | Successful |
| Backend server1 | `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<Backend1>` | Successful |
| Backend server2 | `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<Backend2>` | Successful |
| Backend server2 | `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<Backend2>` | Successful |
| Network load balancer | `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<NLB>` | Successful |
| Network load balancer | `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<NLB>` | ****NOT** Successful** |

Any suggestion of how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
When running `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<NLB>` I get the following error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
        additional info: (unknown error code)
```

Adding the `-d1` option:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ipa.example.com)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ipa.example.com:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP ipa.example.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.141.4.23:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: hostname (ipa.example.com) does not match common name in certificate (ipa2.exmaple.com).
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

So... It seems like I need to attach a certificate to the NLB containing both ipa1 and ipa2 in the certificate?  I'm not sure if this is supported by the cloud provider.

**Note:** I'm not able to SSH into the NLB as it's a managed service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`It seems like I need to attach a certificate to the NLB containing both ipa1 and ipa2 in the certificate?`

No, you need a certificate with `ipa.example.com`, which is the name you seem to be using for the load balancer.

If you also want to be able to contact the LDAP servers directly (bypassing the load balancer), you'll need a certificate with multiple SANs.

Either way, you should install the certificate directly on you LDAP servers, because your load balancer is acting at layer 4 and thus it doesn't terminate the SSL connection, but simply forwards the traffic to one of the servers.

Comment: yes. I managed to figure this out.

Comment: I'll still accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

`TLS: hostname (ipa.example.com) does not match common name in certificate`

The certificate you are using does not have in the SAN the name that the client is connecting to.